# Unity 3D not working

Tags: 11.04, unity, graphics

The first time I installed Ubuntu 11.04, it said that my computer can't run Unity 3D. Now I upgraded my computer a little bit, and I want to try to enable Unity 3D again, but I don't know how. I'm using Unity 2D, if it helps out telling me how to fix it.

Comment: maybe try logging out and selecting Ubuntu from the session menu then login make sure you have Ubuntu and not Ubuntu 2D selected

Comment: Maybe try ubuntu 12.04...

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me.

Open a terminal and try:

```
unity --reset
```

Get a terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Then do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```